# Inserting Images

Tags: graphics, errors

I'm having troubles inserting an image in LaTex. This is what I wrote:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering 
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{hi}
    {desktop/hi.jpg}
    \caption{Placering og budget}
\end{figure}
```

'hi' is the name of the image (pretty random, I know :)). I've tried saving it as both jpg and npg, but nothing works. LaTex says that the problem is within that line, but I'm not sure what the problem is. All it says is: undefined control sequence. 
Anyone got an idea?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Comment: It would help if you would include the complete error message. Anyway: `\includegraphics` has only _one_ mandatory argument, so your `{desktop/hi.jpg}` is not passed to `\includegraphics`.

Comment: You have not given many clues such as telling us _which_ command was undefined, but if it is `\includegraphics` then you have not used `\usepackage{graphicx}` in the preamble of your document. Also note `[H]` should only be used as a last resort (and needs the `float` package before it is defined)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should use both `{hi}` and `{desktop/hi.jpg}` in your code.

Try

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.3]{hi.jpg}
    \caption{Placering og budget}
    \label{fig:hi}
\end{figure}
```

The `hi.jpg` should be located in same directory as the `*.tex` file you are running.
If it is located on the desktop you can use `{../../Desktop/hi.jpg}` instead.

If it is located in a sub directory use `{Folder/hi.jpg}`.

Comment: You can safely omit also the extension of the image file. That is,  `\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{hi}` also should work if the image is in the working directory.